# The AM–GM equality

Tags: real-analysis, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $r_k=\frac{a_k}{S_n}-1$ for $S_n=\sum_{m=1}^n \lambda_{m}a_m$ and $1\le k\le n$, then $(r_k+1)^{\lambda_k}\le e^{\lambda_k r_k}$ for $(r_k)_{k=1}^n\in\mathbb{R_0^+}$ and for $(\lambda_k)_{k=1}^n\in\mathbb{R_0^+}$ since $x+1\le e^x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R_0^+}$. Thus
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (r_k+1)^{\lambda_k}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k}^{\lambda_k}}{\left(\sum_{m=1}^n \lambda_m a_m \right)^{\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k}}$$
and $\prod_{k=1}^n e^{\lambda_k r_k}=e^{\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k r_k}=1.$
We can assume that $\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k =1$ without loss of generality, since $\lambda_k$ can be rescaled accordingly. Therefore
$$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k}^{\lambda _k}}{\sum_{m=1}^n \lambda_m a_m}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k}^{\lambda_k}}{\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k a_k}\le 1$$
which, using the substitution $\lambda_k =\frac{1}{n}$, gives
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n a_k}\le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k.}$$

Now, which conditions must be met for $a_k$ in order to
$$\left\lfloor \sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n a_k}\right\rceil =\left\lfloor\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right\rceil$$
where $\lfloor \rceil$ denotes the *nearest integer function* with the convention that half-integers are rounded to even numbers?

I thought of using the Fourier series,
$$\lfloor x\rceil =x+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{j\gt 0}\frac{(-1)^j \sin 2\pi jx}{j}\quad x\notin\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2},$$
though I don't know how would I get anything from that.

Comment: If $A\le B$ then $\lfloor A\rceil\le\lfloor B\rceil$... Lol?

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch There was a mistake. It is supposed to be $\lfloor A\rceil =\lfloor B\rceil$.

Comment: Okay now I am not quite sure what type of condition you are looking for

Comment: Something like [this is made up] $\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k}^2\le \frac{1}{2}$ and so on.